# Rails - keeping the quotes inside helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

tried searching around to no avail. I want to keep the quotes in the string output from my helper exactly as they are when i call the helper with escape_javascript in the haml file

helper

```
def popOver_javascript_for_feedback_index(feedbacks)
  js = ""
  feedbacks.each do |fb|
    js += "$('span[rel=\"fb#{fb.id}\"]').popover();"
  end
  js += ""
end
```

haml

```
:javascript
  $(document).ready(function() {
    #{escape_javascript popOver_javascript_for_feedback_index(@feedbacks)}
  });
```

in the output i am getting

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(\'span[rel=\"fb1\"]\').popover();
}
```

when i really want

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('span[rel="fb1"]').popover();
}
```

tried a variation of h(), raw(), html_safe in vain.... what am i missing here?

thanks much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove escape_javascript. !!!!